# Why is my PeerJS audio chat app not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, audio-streaming, peerjs

I have an apache server running php and my front end peerjs code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        //returns element value of GET key (e.g '&test=2'returns 2)
        function getParameterByName(name){
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        function getAudio(successCallback, errorCallback){
            navigator.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: false
            }, successCallback, errorCallback);
        }

        //request call
        var from = getParameterByName('from');
        var to = getParameterByName('to');

        $('#start-call').click(function(){

            console.log('starting call...');

            getAudio(
                function(MediaStream){

                    console.log('now calling ' + to);
                    var call = peer.call(to, MediaStream);
                    call.on('stream', onReceiveStream);
                },
                function(err){
                    console.log('an error occured while getting the audio');
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );

        });
        //recieve call
        function onReceiveCall(call){

            console.log('peer is calling...');
            console.log(call);

            getAudio(
                function(MediaStream){
                    call.answer(MediaStream);
                    console.log('answering call started...');
                },
                function(err){
                    console.log('an error occured while getting the audio');
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );

            call.on('stream', onReceiveStream);
        }

        function onReceiveStream(stream){
            var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
            audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            audio.onloadedmetadata = function(e){
                console.log('now playing the audio');
                audio.play();
            }
        }

        var peer = new Peer({host: 'www.example.com', port:9000, path:''});
        peer.on('open', function(id) {
          console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
        });

        peer.on('call', onReceiveCall);

    });
</script>
<div id = "start-call"> Start Call </div>
<audio controls></audio>
```

And then I have a node server that runs the peer server on port 9000:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;

var server = PeerServer({
  port: 9000,
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/xxx/xxx/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/xxx/xxx/cert.pem')
  },
  proxied: true
});

server.on('connection', function(id) {
  console.log("connecion made:" + id);
});
```

Using chrome, no errors appear in the front end console and I do get the prompt `"Connection made: 35hy2o4ydfqw"`.
So when I click start call, the console does output `"now calling xxx..."` however nothing is received at all on the other side, so i assume it is

```
peer.on('call', onReceiveCall);
```

The call is not received. Very little hints are given as to what is going wrong  on the receivers end, absolutely nothing happens.

Thank you for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in localhost or your remote website. If you are working on your remote website, make sure you have a secure(HTTS) site. Navigator.getUserMedia is only available on SSL websites.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit this line `var peer = new Peer(from, {host: 'www.example.com', port:9000, path:''});`

`from` - this is id for call